# I can't link to a new page with active class by JavaScript on PHP

Tags: javascript, php

I'm a new learner on PHP. I can't solve any problem on my code.

In **sidebar.php**

```
<nav class="side-bar">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="index.php" class="category active">
                    <i class="fi fi-bs-home"></i>
                    <span>Home</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#" class="category">
                    <i class="fi fi-bs-apps"></i>
                    <span>Room</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="contact.php" class="category">
                    <i class="fi fi-br-comment-alt"></i>
                    <span>Contact</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            </ul>
</nav>
```

In **script.js**

```
const category = document.querySelectorAll('.category');

category.forEach(cate =>{
    cate.addEventListener('click',()=>{
        removeClass();
        cate.classList.add('active');
    })
})

function removeClass(){
    category.forEach(cate=>{
        cate.classList.remove('active');
    })
}
```

In **index.php**

```
#code
<?php include ("sidebar.php"); ?>
#code
```

but the active class is not highlighted when I link to a new page, but it works if I use href="#" in  tag. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: You voice your problem as: _"active class not working"_. What does this active class do, that it doesn't do? Is it used to highlight the link of the page you're currently on?

Comment: Yes. It's use for highlights the link of the page we currently on

Comment: When you click on the href link it's fired first that your listner call the function.  So try to remove href link and execute the redirect by javascript inside your function.

Comment: When you link to a new page, the javascript becomes irrelevant. You should render the `class="active"` on the server, for the corresponding page that's being loaded.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the colors you want to use when an item is active and when an item is visited, but not active. You may choose the colors you prefer instead of the ones I have chosen.

```js
const category = document.querySelectorAll('.category');

category.forEach(cate =>{
    cate.addEventListener('click',()=>{
        removeClass();
        cate.classList.add('active');
    })
})

function removeClass(){
    category.forEach(cate=>{
        cate.classList.remove('active');
    })
}
```

```css
a.active {
    color: #7F7FEE;
}

a, a:not(.active):visited {
    color: #0000FF;
}
```

```html
<nav class="side-bar">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="index.php" class="category active">
                    <i class="fi fi-bs-home"></i>
                    <span>Home</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#" class="category">
                    <i class="fi fi-bs-apps"></i>
                    <span>Room</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="contact.php" class="category">
                    <i class="fi fi-br-comment-alt"></i>
                    <span>Contact</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            </ul>
</nav>
```